# Retry downloading in websave Matlab

Tags: matlab, download

I am going to save a number of 315 files from a url with websave  Matlab function. During download an Error occurs. 
Error using websave (line 103)
The error "Error copying data." occurred while communicating with URL

Are there any options for websave function to retry the download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For stuff like this I use a retry pattern

```
for i = 1:374
    reTryCatch(@() websave(fn(i),url(i)), 'Too many retries ... skip this round', @warning, 3);
end

function [varargout] = reTryCatch( fh, errorMsg, notifyHandle, retryCnt)
if nargin < 4
    retryCnt = 2;
end
if nargin < 3
    notifyHandle = @error;
end

for i = 1:retryCnt
   try
       if nargout > 0
           [varargout{1:nargout}] = fh();  
       else
           fh();
       end
       return;
   catch ex
       if i == retryCnt
           varargout = cell(1,nargout);
           notifyHandle('%s\n Exception was: %s',errorMsg, ex.message);
       else
           pause(0.1);
       end
   end
end
end
```

Comment: My code is similar :

for i=1:315
    if exist(file(i), 'file')
    else
        websave(file(i));
    end
end